# impixel in realtime video input (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I want to acquire a video input from the webcam and simultaneously plot the intensity of pixels along a certain vertical line.
The vertical line is constant for the entire video.
Basically the output would be the webcam output and an intensity plot just underneath it simultaneously.
Is this possible in MATLAB? any other software suggestions?
also, what does this code plot exactly?

```
function realVideo()

% Define frame rate
NumberFrameDisplayPerSecond=10;

% Open figure
hFigure=figure(1);

% Set-up webcam video input
try
   % For windows
   vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1);
catch
   try
      % For macs.
      vid = videoinput('macvideo', 1);
   catch
      errordlg('No webcam available');
   end
end

% Set parameters for video
% Acquire only one frame each time
set(vid,'FramesPerTrigger',1);
% Go on forever until stopped
set(vid,'TriggerRepeat',Inf);
% Get a grayscale image
set(vid,'ReturnedColorSpace','grayscale');
triggerconfig(vid, 'Manual');

% set up timer object
TimerData=timer('TimerFcn', {@FrameRateDisplay,vid},'Period',1/NumberFrameDisplayPerSecond,'ExecutionMode','fixedRate','BusyMode','drop');

% Start video and timer object
start(vid);
start(TimerData);

% We go on until the figure is closed
uiwait(hFigure);

% Clean up everything
stop(TimerData);
delete(TimerData);
stop(vid);
delete(vid);
% clear persistent variables
clear functions;

% This function is called by the timer to display one frame of the figure

function FrameRateDisplay(obj, event,vid)
persistent IM;
persistent handlesRaw;
persistent handlesPlot;
trigger(vid);
IM=getdata(vid,1,'uint8');

if isempty(handlesRaw)
   % if first execution, we create the figure objects
   subplot(2,1,1);
   handlesRaw=imagesc(IM);
   title('CurrentImage');

   % Plot first value
   Values=mean(IM(:));
   subplot(2,1,2);
   handlesPlot=plot(Values);
   title('Average of Frame');
   xlabel('Frame number');
   ylabel('Average value (au)');
else
   % We only update what is needed
   set(handlesRaw,'CData',IM);
   Value=mean(IM(:));
   OldValues=get(handlesPlot,'YData');
   set(handlesPlot,'YData',[OldValues Value]);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided plots the current frame and mean intensity for every frame from beginning to current:

```
Value=mean(IM(:)); % obtain current mean
OldValues=get(handlesPlot,'YData'); % get mean for every frame until the last one
set(handlesPlot,'YData',[OldValues Value]); add current mean to the old ones
```

If you want to plot intensity along a particular vertical line (given by xPos), do something like:

```
Values = IM(:, xPos);
```

to get it and then one of these:

```
handlesPlot=plot(Values); % for first frame
set(handlesPlot,'YData',Values); % for all the others (else-part)
```

to draw/update the plot.